# Tableau shift data

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to push my data in Tableau by one cell. My current data is in the format below:

```
Month | Actual
--------------
  1   |   0
  2   |   x
  3   |   y
  4   |   z
```

I want to create a calculated field that will push the data in actual by one cell based on a condition such that I have a new field as expected below:

```
Month | Actual | Expected
-------------------------
  1   |   0    |    0
  2   |   x    |    0
  3   |   y    |    x
  4   |   z    |    y
```

It will be helpful if anybody can tell me a correct way of updating the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a table calculation, but it is important how you show the data in your view.

Create a new calculated field and use the following logic:

`IFNULL(LOOKUP(MAX([Actual]),-1),'0')`

Your view and output should look like this:

[image]